# Asp net Core Identity token authentication expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use asp net core Identity. This is what I am trying to do and I have no Idea how to do this so need some expert help on this. When a new user registers in my application , a password reset link is sent to the person's email, Now when the link token in the link has expired and the user clicks on the link I need to show a message as token expired. How do I find out If the token has expired or not when the user clicks on the link which is in the email. Can any one suggest ways to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Your question is very broad and doesn't necessarily ask a question about the ASP.NET core Identity token authentication expiration specifically.

You should have a look at the ASP.NET Identity documentation at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core has a built-in Claims system to store information about the user .

To do that ,

1. add a helper method to store the expiration datetime in `Register.cshtml.cs`:

   ```
   private async Task AddTokenExpirationInfo(IdentityUser user, int span=1*24*60)
   {
       var expiresAt = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(span));
       var tokenExpiredAtClaim = new Claim("ActivtationTokenExpiredAt", expiresAt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks.ToString());
       await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, tokenExpiredAtClaim);
   }
   ```
2. add a helper method to check whether the token has expired in the `ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs` :

   ```
   private async Task<bool> TokenExpiredValidate(IdentityUser user) {
       var claims = (await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user))
           .Where(c => c.Type == "ActivtationTokenExpiredAt");
       var expiredAt = claims.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
       bool expired = true;    // default value
       if (expiredAt != null)
       {
           var expires = Convert.ToInt64(expiredAt);
           var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
           expired= now <= expires? false : true;
       }
       else {
           expired = false;
       }
       // clear claims
       await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, claims);
       return expired;
   }
   ```
3. invoke `AddTokenExpirationInfo` when there's a registeration request :

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
   {
       returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
           var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
               _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

               var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
               var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                   "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                   pageHandler: null,
                   values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                   protocol: Request.Scheme);

               await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                   $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

               ///////////////// invoke here  ////////////////////
               AddTokenExpirationInfo(user);

               await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
               return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
           }
           foreach (var error in result.Errors)
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
           }
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       return Page();
   }
   ```
4. invoke `TokenExpiredValidate` in your `ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs`:

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
   {
       if (userId == null || code == null)
       {
           return RedirectToPage("/Index");
       }

       var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
       if (user == null)
       {
           return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
       }
       var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
       if (!result.Succeeded)
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"Error confirming email for user with ID '{userId}':");
       }
       if (await TokenExpiredValidate(user)) 
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"Token has alread expired '{userId}':");

       return Page();
   }
   ```

When a user registers , there' will be a record in the `AspNetUserClaims` table :

[image: Demo]

When a user confirmed successfully , the record will be removed . Just as a reminder , a more robust method is to use a background service to clear the expired record .

Comment: Thanks, That helped